# How do I return the count for both matching column in a single return

Tags: sql, sql-server, count, subquery

I'm trying to get a number of count for exist and non-exist for my validation to insert my data. As refer to the image below, I'm inserting 3 data in which 1 data consist of same ID number as destination table, 1 data consist of same quotation number as destination table and the last data is a new entry.

Okay here's my requirement. I am sending my source table data to insert into the dest table. So before inserting, I want to do validation by mapping the entire dest table like this:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM sourceTable WHERE exists(
SELECT * FROM sourceTable WHERE QuotationId IN
(SELECT A.QuotationId FROM sourceTable A
JOIN DestTable B ON A.QuotationId = B.QuotationId
JOIN DestTable C ON A.QuotationNum = C.QuotationNum)
```

[image]

Comment: In your question, you use: "ID number" and "quotation number". In your picture the columnnames are: "QuotationId" and "QuotationNum".  Why do you not use the same naming in both places?     Also it is unclear how you are comparing the source table to the dest table (or how you want that to be done, because you do not show what your tried )

Comment: Okay here's my requirement. I am sending my source table data to insert into the dest table. So before inserting, I want to do validation by mapping the entire dest table like this:

SELECT COUNT(*) FROM sourceTable WHERE exists(
SELECT * FROM sourceTable WHERE QuotationId IN
(SELECT A.QuotationId FROM sourceTable A
JOIN DestTable B ON A.QuotationId = B.QuotationId
JOIN DestTable C ON A.QuotationNum = C.QuotationNum)

Comment: @DigitalInsanity  Please edit and add that information to the question.

Answer (score 0):

Without further details on table structure and so on it's difficult to tell, but something like the following might do the trick:

```
WITH cteMatch AS(
  SELECT s.QuotationID AS src, d.QuotationID as dst
    FROM sourceTable s
    LEFT JOIN destTable d
)
SELECT CASE WHEN dst IS NULL THEN N'NonExist' ELSE N'Exist' END AS ValExist, COUNT(*) cnt
  FROM cteMatch
  GROUP BY CASE WHEN dst IS NULL THEN N'NonExist' ELSE N'Exist' END
```

Comment: I did try on this but it doesn't work. My output still giving the amount of record in source table for NonExists.

Comment: And you are sure you are joining in the correct Key?

Answer (score 0):

You seem to want:

```
select count(*) 
from sourcetable s
where exists(
    select 1 
    from desttable d 
    where d.quotationid = s.quotationid or d.quotationnum = s.quotationnum
)
```

This counts how many rows in the source table have a quotation id or num that exists in the target table. If you want the count of both existing and non-existing rows, I would recommend:

```
select sum(flag) as cnt_exists, sum(1 - flag) as cnt_not_exists
from (
    select 
        case when exists (
            select 1 
            from desttable d 
            where d.quotationid = s.quotationid or d.quotationnum = s.quotationnum
        ) then 1 else 0 end as flag
    from sourcetable s
) t
```